# place Processing language on top of DataTable

Tags: datatables

Is there a way to put the "Processing..." language on the top of the DataTable object instead of in the middle vertically? If I have a long table, it is hidden off the page because its default position is in the middle.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
      "processing": "DataTables is currently busy"
  }
} );
```

Comment: Quick Tip: As you stated "it is hidden off the page because its default position is in the middle", You can use `div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_processing {position: fixed;}`.  It will make your processing text always visible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the following CSS rule and adjust `top` as you wish.

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_processing {
   top: 5%;
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pffnxy9/) for demonstration.

Comment: Works but I had to use `#transactions-table_processing` to target the message.